# Zebra P4T Setup

Tags: zebra-printers

I just got my hands on a P4T mobile printer today at work, I have to set it up for wireless acess.

I installed drivers, Zebra Setup Utility, etc. but its a no go. When I try to print a test page from printer properties or send a command from the Setup Utility I get a printer error and printer goes into error status. Im running Windows 8 x64.

Im wondering if the issue might be the blinking out-of-media icon on the printer display that wont let me send any command to the printer for its setup.

Any help is very welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the printer from receiving print jobs when the printer is out of media there is a usb_halt and comm_halt. Put media in the printer to get rid of the error then you can set the wireless settings. If you do not want to see that happen the next time you are out of media turn off those settings.

! U1 setvar "usb.halt" "no"

! U1 setvar "comm.halt" "no"

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the Zebra Setup Utilities? You can download from the Zebra P4T official support website. Then, in addition, you can install Label Vista to set properties like bluetooth or for test the printer.